# Source to learn about Hadamard's parametrix construction?

Tags: differential-geometry

I have been tasked with learning about the Hadamard parametrix construction, and applying it to the Dirac operator (first the constant coefficient Dirac operator, but eventually the variable coefficient Dirac operator). Unfortunately, I have not found any sources to learn about this construction except wikipedia's short section "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrix#Hadamard_parametrix_construction".

Does anyone know of any good sources?

Comment: You probably want PDE and perhaps other differential operator or functional analysis tags.

Answer (score 1):

The best source I know of is Hörmander III, the Hadamard parametric construction is treated in $\S$17.3.